# How to set a foreign key in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I need to set a field from another collection as a foreign key  to my mongoose schema.

I have a counter `pid`  to `productSchema`. I need to set `pid` as a foreignkey to `orderSchema`

```
    const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    product: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product', 
    required: 
    true },
    quantity: { type: Number, default: 1 }
    });

    const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    productImage: { type: String }
    });
```

Comment: I don't see any pid in productSchema are you talking your _id as pid?

Answer (score 0):

Well MongoDB is not a relational DB so it does not support concepts like foreign key. In mongoDB you have to structure your data in such a way that you can fetch information easily.

You should see if you can go with Aggregation or something but mongoDB does not have foreign keys. More important you should make correct choice when you are creating a DB , you should select appropriate DB according to your requirements.